# What does Bad Origin mean, while trying to transfer DOTs?

Tags: polkadot

I am trying to transfer DOT from one wallet to another and it's failing with "Bad Origin" message. What does that mean? How can I resolve it. I am keeping enough balance necessary as well as that's needed for transaction fees. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to send a transaction while transfers on Polkadot were still disabled.

Transferability unlocked at block 1,205,128. From that point on, any DOT holder could transfer DOT tokens, provided they have the necessary DOT to execute a transaction.

Try again and it should work now.